# Customize sections' numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want to customize my sections to look like the following but I don't know how to do it.
Can somebody help ?

[image: How I want my section's number to look like]

Comment: What are V, 1, 2 supposed to be? Part, chapter, section numbers? Which document class?

Comment: Exact, V, 1, 2 are supposed to be Chapter, Section, Subsection. I'm using the book document class.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}` in the preamble should do in a normal setup